# Meteor.js: Parsing CSV on the server and passing back to client with node-csv-string

Tags: node.js, csv, meteor

I'm working on a project that involves parsing a CSV-like file where the delimiter is determined on parse.

I've been using PapaParse, but unfortunately the delimiter checking doesn't seem robust enough, so I'm using https://github.com/touv/node-csv-string instead. So far so good.

I've installed `meteorhacks:npm` and `meteorhacks:async` but I'm uncertain how to pass the parsing request back and forth between the server and the client. I understand that I need to be doing this with callbacks since it's async, just not sure how to go about it.

On my client side, this is what I have:

```
var parsedData = Meteor.call("parseCSV", data);
```

On the server, I'm using a method something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  parseCSV: function (data) {
    var CSV = Meteor.npmRequire('csv-string');
    return CSV.parse(data);
  }
});
```

Though that clearly won't cut it because of the async requirements. I tried something like

```
var response = Async.runSync(function(done) {
  CSV.parse((data), function(err, data) {
    done(null, data);
    console.log(data)
  });
});
```

But honestly it was a stab in the dark, and it hasn't worked. I need to be able to access the parsed CSV through `parsedData` in the client. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Meteor's [`Meteor.wrapAsync`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) method.

```
Meteor.methods({
  parseCSV: function (data) {
    var CSV = Meteor.npmRequire('csv-string');
    var parse = Meteor.wrapAsync(CSV.parse);
    return parse(data);
  }
});
```

The reason this occurs is because Meteor is using node Fibers and requires you to have synchronous code. You could also implement a fiber / future and send the output within the callback, but that is a more complicated solution and may not be needed.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty neat functionality. No dice though, I'm afraid — my terminal's returning some regex errors:
`I20150209-20:09:12.545(-5)? Exception while invoking method 'parseCSV' SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression…`

and so on. Looks like it might be something with node-csv-string?

Comment: That seems like an error with formatting. If you look at the documentation for [parse](https://github.com/touv/node-csv-string#parseinput--string-separator--string--object) it says the input is a string. Is the data you are passing to it a string? But, it could be an error with node-csv-string

Comment: Yeah, I think it's an error with node-csv-string, seems like it's choking on something in my test data set. Oh well. I'm accepting your answer since it seems like this would've worked — I'm just switching to a different library and hoping for the best. Thanks!